# Search form returning all pages

Tags: search

My search form is returning all of the sites pages, regardless of the search term used.

Even if I search for a load of random letters (dfbdsufbsf) all pages are returned.

This is my search form code.  I've tried changing the button to and  but no joy

```
      <form class='form form--search' role='search' action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
        <fieldset>
          <div class='input'>
            <label class='hidden' for='q'>Search</label>
            <input class='form__input form__input--search' placeholder="Search" name='q' id="q" tabindex='1' type='search'>
            <button class='form--search__button' type="submit"></button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

And here is my search results page (search/results.html) (markup removed)

```
{#
 # Search template
 # ---------------
#}

{% extends "_layout" %}
{% block content %}
  {% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
  {% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

    <h1 class='hero__title hero__title--news'>Search Results</h1>
    {% if entries|length %}
        <p>{{ entries|length }} results:</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Your search for “{{ query }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
    {% endif %}


    {% if entries|length %}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas why this is happening.  I'm using the latest version of Craft.  This is happening locally and on production.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't have anything in my htaccess.
Is it normal that when I'm searching for 'test' and click on the search button it returns me all pages and the URL is : index.php?Q=test.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted.

It was a .htaccess issue

One of my redirects had a typo in it

```
RewriteRule ^old-page$ /new-page [R=301,L#]
```

should be

```
RewriteRule ^old-page$ /new-page [R=301,L]
```